# Segmented Control in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anybody know how implement a javascript for this segmented control? This segmented control acts like a group radio button.

```
<style>
.buttonGroup
{
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-pack:justify;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttonGroup > li
{
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        border: solid 1px #9a9a99;
        border-left: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        background-image:
                -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                        from(#fbfbfb),
                        to(#bdbdbd));
        color: #6b6b6b;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup > li:first-child
{
        border-left: solid 1px #9a9a99;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup > li:last-child
{
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup > li.selected
{
        background-image:
                -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                        from(#2a55b1),
                        to(#6297f2));
        color: #fff;
        border-color: #193a7f;
}
</style>

<ul class="buttonGroup">
  <li class="selected">Navigate</li>
  <li>Points</li>
  <li>Lines</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is full code with the answer from below. It is not working. Nothing is happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <title>Segmental Control panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/iphone.css" />

    <script language="javascript"> 
    <!--
    var state = 'none';

    function showhide(layer_ref) {

    if (state == 'block') { 
    state = 'none'; 
    } 
    else { 
    state = 'block'; 
    } 
    if (document.getElementById &&!document.all) { 
    hza = document.getElementById(layer_ref); 
    hza.style.display = state; 
    } 
    } 
    //--> 
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.onload = function() {
          setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0, 1);}, 100);
        }
    </script>

<style>
.buttonGroup
{
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-pack:justify;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttonGroup > li
{
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        border: solid 1px #9a9a99;
        border-left: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        background-image:
                -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                        from(#fbfbfb),
                        to(#bdbdbd));
        color: #6b6b6b;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup > li:first-child
{
        border-left: solid 1px #9a9a99;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup > li:last-child
{
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup > li.selected
{
        background-image:
                -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                        from(#2a55b1),
                        to(#6297f2));
        color: #fff;
        border-color: #193a7f;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

      var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("UL");

      for(var i=0, j=ul.length; i<j; i++) {
      if ( /\bbuttonGroup\b/.test(ul[i].className) ) {
          ul[i].onclick = segmentedController(ul[i]);
         }
      }

      function segmentedController(target) {
      return function(event) {
          var li = target.getElementsByTagName("LI");
          for (var i=0, j=li.length; i<j; i++) {
              var _ = li[i];
              _.className = _.className.replace(/\bselected\b/, "");
              if (_ === event.target) _.className += " selected"; 
          }
        }
      }

</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Segmented Control</h1>
        <a href="index.html" id="backButton">Index</a>
    </div>

    <h1>Examples</h1>


  <ul class="buttonGroup">
      <li class="selected">Navigate</li>
      <li>Points</li>
      <li>Lines</li>
      <li>Polygons</li>
      <li>Modify</li>
      <li>Drag</li>
 </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

I need something like (below) in javascript. Code below is jquery mobile.

```
<form id="controls">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" 

    data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <input id="nav" type="radio" name="controls" value="nav" checked="checked">
                            <label for="nav">navigate</label>
                            <input id="point" type="radio" name="controls" value="point">
                            <label for="point">point</label>
                            <input id="line" type="radio" name="controls" value="line">
                            <label for="line">line</label>
                            <input id="poly" type="radio" name="controls" value="poly">
                            <label for="poly">poly</label>
                            <input id="mod" type="radio" name="controls" value="mod">
                            <label for="mod">modify</label>
                            <input id="drag" type="radio" name="controls" value="drag">
                            <label for="drag">drag</label>
                            <input id="select" type="radio" name="controls" value="select">
                            <label for="select">select</label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

$("#nav, #point, #line, #poly, #mod, #drag, #select").change(function(event) {
    deactivateControls();
    // jquery mobile bug regarding change makes us go through all inputs
    // https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/issue/1088
    var val = $("input:radio[name=controls]:checked").val();
    if (val !== "nav") {
        map.getControlsBy("id", val + "-control")[0].activate();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is segmented control http://media.miekd.com/segmented_control/#

Answer (score 9):

Pure JavaScript solution ([see it](http://jsfiddle.net/LdZk8/))

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("UL");

for(var i=0, j=ul.length; i<j; i++) {
    if ( /\bbuttonGroup\b/.test(ul[i].className) ) {
        ul[i].onclick = segmentedController(ul[i]);
    }
}

function segmentedController(target) {
    return function(event) {
        var li = target.getElementsByTagName("LI");
        for (var i=0, j=li.length; i<j; i++) {
            var _ = li[i];
            _.className = _.className.replace(/\bselected\b/, "");
            if (_ === event.target) _.className += " selected"; 
        }
    }
}
```

jQuery solution ([see it](http://jsfiddle.net/LdZk8/1/))

```
$("ul.buttonGroup").click(function (event) {
    $("li", this)
    .removeClass("selected")
    .filter(event.target)
    .addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: +1 for pure js. BTW in your js you could chnage the signature to `segmentedController` right? I dont see why you should pass `this`

Comment: Tomalak, thanks for your answer. But it did not work in my case. Please see the full code above. I could not use jquery solution, it is already working in jQuery mobile.

Comment: @ns-1m: Either move the script to the end of the page (just before `</body>`) or wrap it in an `init()` function and call that at `<body onload="init()">`. At the time the script loads in your example code, the page body is not even rendered yet.

Comment: As instructed, I put function init(){...} and <body onload="init()">. It makes it a list, not a segmented control. Nothing is selected. Navigate is not even selected as default.

Comment: What I want is just like this http://media.miekd.com/segmented_control/# but not that fancy - no animation. Just simple but not jquery. Simple javascript.

Comment: BTW, your answer work as a List in jsfiddle.net. Not a segmented control.

Comment: @ns-1m All I can say it that it works in my browser. I can select stuff in your XHTML (once it was fixed) and in the jsFiddle as well. What browser do you use and did you actually check what happens in any sort of JS developer tools? Psychic debugging is not my strong suit, so without any more detailed hints I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: No errors in Safari and Firefox in Mac OS X. However, it is just normal list. Nothing is clickable. Nothing happens when you click in the list. Again, the codes makes my segmented list - a normal list. Firefox is saying now - The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless.

Comment: @ns-m1: Let me give you a tip for copying code off the internet. *Read* it. *Understand* what it does and how it works. Do not use it until you completely understood it. That your copycat CSS does not work in Firefox has *no connection whatsoever* to the JavaScript in my answer. Also, pasting some code you found somewhere into StackOverflow along with a mere "please make it work" is not how this website is meant. No offense, but you will have to do a little thinking of your own.

Comment: @Tomalak, Sorry CSS does is not working in Firefox. You got a normal list, not segmented control. However, if you view it in Safari, you will see the segmented control. My mistaken of asking a question to general, I should have mentioned that I need a segmented control that works in safari and iOS devices (iPad and iPhone). BTW, the jquery mobile codes are my own. Segmented control is working properly in my jQuery mobile but I problems with hybrid framework (Xcode and JS) that I am using that jQuery mobile could handle properly.

Comment: @Tomalak BTW, webkit is not compatible with firefox. You can see that the CSS (e.g.  display: -webkit-box;) is intended for webkit browser at first place.

Comment: I am taking my words about firefox not compatible with webkit. http://www.techspot.com/news/38166-new-firefox-javascript-engine-uses-webkit-code.html

Comment: @ns-1m: It works for me on Chrome (i.e. Webkit), and for all I know it should work on Safari. *(It does not look nice on Firefox because the CSS is Webkit-specific, but that seems to be OK with you.)* Anyway, the example on jsFiddle does what it is supposed to do. So, if the jsFiddle runs on an iPad/Phone, the my code is fine. If and if it does not run on iOS, I frankly have no idea how to help you, I do not own such a device.

Comment: @ns-1m - your question was about what JavaScript you needed to get the control to work. Tomalak has given you JS code with a working example. Problems with how it displays relate to your CSS, so if you now need help on getting your CSS to work post a separate question about that. Though I'd suggest you try changing the `li` class to have `display: inline-block;` or `display: inline;` instead of `display: block;`.

Answer (score 1):

Put a click handler on the `<ul>` element. The handler will remove the "selected" class from the previously selected `<li>` and add the "selected" class to the new selection. Something like this:

```
<ul class="buttonControl" id="buttonControl">
  <li class="selected">Navigate</li>
  <li>Points</li>
  <li>Lines</li>
</ul>

<script>
//put this within onload/onready/whatever
(function() {
  var buttonControl = document.getElementById("buttonControl");
  var buttons = buttonControl.getElementsByTagName("LI");

  buttonControl.onclick = function(e) {
    // half-hearted attempt at cross-browser compatibility,
    // where normally I'd just use jQuery
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;

    // just return if the clicked item was already selected
    if (/\bselected\b/.test(target.className))
      return;
    else
      target.className += " selected";

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
      if (buttons[i] !== target)
        buttons[i].className = buttons[i].className.replace(/\bselected\b/, "");
  }
})();

</script>
```

EDIT: Oops, probably not a good idea to type up most of an answer in another editor, get distracted and do something else, then come back and finish up and post without checking for other answers. Oh well, seems a shame to throw this away since I took a different approach to Tomalak in that I attached my event handler to the ul element. I haven't tested it, and am not going to bother given there's already another answer that works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this one did not work as well. Putting id="buttonControl" make the control vertical, not horizontal segmented. It becomes a list. I need a segmented control.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I attached my event handler to the `<ul>` element as well. ;-)

Comment: @nnnnnn: Anyway, +1 for the event target cross compatibility.

Comment: @ns-1m - putting an id won't affect the display of the element at all unless your stylesheet has an entry for that id, so I don't know what's happening there. From your comments in Tomalak's answer it sounds like your CSS is dodgy. @Tomalak - oops, yes, sorry, for some reason I initially read your non-jQuery answer as attaching to the LIs when it doesn't.