# JQuery/CSS - Segmented Control

Tags: jquery, css

I found a great post over [Segmented Control in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702985/segmented-control-in-javascript) that mentioned a great solution to creating a segmented control, the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LdZk8/1/

The jquery is quite short which is great:

```
$("ul.buttonGroup").click(function (event) {
    $("li", this)
    .removeClass("selected")
    .filter(event.target)
    .addClass("selected");
});
```

My problem is this is working great in safari and chrome but it isn't rendering properly in firefox.  Just view the fiddle in firefox and hit run and you will see.

Does anyone know how I can correct this? I believe it's CSS related and maybe the webkit elements are being ignoring, but I'm not sure how to fix this for FF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only working great in Chrome/Safari because you've included `-webkit-` browser effects and not the `-moz-`, `ms` and general equivalents, which you would need to get the same effects in Firefox and IE.

For example, when you include [-webkit-box-flex](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-box-flex) you'd need to include [-moz-box-flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-box-flex) too for Firefox compatibility.

Some useful links:

**[Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)** - find definitions/syntax of various CSS3 properties.

**[ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)** - get other browsers equivalent syntax by simply pasting webkit version.

Comment: Is there a good site/place where I can determine what the equivalents are? Or should I not be using browser specific CSS?

Comment: @Geesu developer.mozilla.org :) Normally you can just type in your webkit property into google, and ones for -moz- and -ms- will come up in the results too!

Comment: Using http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ is a HUGE help as well. I can paste the css I have it will give me one that works with other browsers!